# How can I filter functions/aliases to find only user-defined ones?

Tags: bash, function, alias

I am trying to review information about functions and aliases and use this function to show me the definitions of them. However, it does not show just the functions / aliases defined by my profile scripts, and shows a lot of other things (that I am not so interested in).

- Would there be a way to just show the functions / aliases that were specifically setup in `.bashrc` `.profile` etc (i.e. user defined functions / aliases)?
- Would it be possible to see the date/time that the function or aliase was defined in this shell and would it be possible to see the source like `.bashrc` or `.profile` etc (aybe such information is not retained, but all command history date/time stamps are so it's possible I guess)?

```
def ()
{
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        declare -F;
        printf "\nAbove listing is all defined functions 'declare -F' (use def <func-name> to show function contents)\nType 'alias' to show all aliases (def <alias-nam> to show alias definition, where 'def' uses 'command -V <name>')\n\n";
    else
        command -V $1;
    fi
}
```

Comment: In terms of how I'd do this _personally_, I'd start your dotfiles initializing an associative array listing the items that were already defined, and filter them out from the display function (using an associative array specifically means you get O(1) lookup performance, though if you're targeting MacOS with its ancient bash 3.2 that stops being an option).

Comment: ...however, it's a very broad question, insofar as the objective it states can be accomplished multiple ways. (bash doesn't track what _time_ a function was defined, but it does track where the code that defined it came from -- as is necessary for `BASH_SOURCE` and similar values to be set correctly at runtime).

Comment: ...that said, note that the source file is only tracked for _functions_ and not _aliases_ (as aliases aren't really even a language feature at all; they're just prefix substitution that takes place before the parser does any real analysis; since they "don't exist" past parse time, they aren't present in stack traces, so their source file doesn't need to be tracked)

Comment: BTW, consider `printf '%s\n' 'first line' 'second line' '' 'the previous line was blank'` when you want to print multiple lines. If `'\n'` is the only escape sequence you ever use, no reason to repeat it.

Comment: I'd love to see how you'd do it personally Charles, sounds really interesting and useful(!). I keep away from MacOS, they are "not computers" imo . ok, no timing on function creation. ah, `BASH_SOURCE`, sounds interesting. I guess I can do without knowing aliases, that would be a "nice to have". I'll fix the `printf`, thanks for the tip, good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, caching the list of known functions at the top of your dotfiles (so anything not so cached can be considered as unknown):

```
declare -A -g predefined_commands

populate_predefined_commands() {
  local line fndec_re alias_re
  fndec_re='^declare -f ([^[:space:]]+)$'
  alias_re='^alias ([^[:space:]=])+='
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $fndec_re ]] && predefined_commands[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=1
  done < <(declare -F)
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $alias_re ]] && predefined_commands[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=1
  done < <(alias -p)
}

def() {
  if [[ $1 ]]; then
    command -V -- "$1"
    return
  fi

  local line fndec_re alias_re
  fndec_re='^declare -f ([^[:space:]]+)$'
  alias_re='^alias ([^[:space:]=])+='
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $fndec_re ]] && [[ ${predefined_commands[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]} ]] && continue
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done < <(declare -F)
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $alias_re ]] && [[ ${predefined_commands[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]} ]] && continue
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done < <(alias -p)
}

# do this AFTER calling def, or else def itself will show up as a new function
populate_predefined_commands; unset -f populate_predefined_commands
```